# Django crispy-forms: 2 column form with a TextArea field

Tags: django, layout, django-forms, textarea, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to create a good looking 2 column form using [crispy-forms Layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html). Its getting messy when 1 of the fields is a `TextArea` field. 
(And all works fine when i do not have `TextArea` fields)

This code:

```
## forms.py
class BasicForm(forms.Form):
   label_1 = forms.CharField(label='label1')
   label_2 = forms.CharField(label='label2')
   label_3 = forms.CharField(label='label3',help_text='This is help text', widget=forms.Textarea)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Field('label_1', wrapper_class='col-md-6', css_class='row-fluid'),
            ),

            Row(
                Field('label_2', wrapper_class='col-md-6', css_class='row-fluid'),
                Field('label_3', wrapper_class='col-md-6')
            )
        )
```

Yields this format:
[image: 1]

And this code:

```
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Row(
            Field('label_1', wrapper_class='col-md-6', css_class='row-fluid'),
            Field('label_3', wrapper_class='col-md-6')
        ),

        Row(
            Field('label_2', wrapper_class='col-md-6', css_class='row-fluid')
        )
    )
```

Yields this format:
[image]

I want to separate the 2 columns, each 1 should be stacked to the top, relatively to itself only.

### EDIT

(Adding my desired final outcome sketch)

Something like:
[image]

And say i have even more field:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what your desired outcome is? Perhaps you could make a drawing and attach it? I don't know what you mean by "I want to separate the 2 columns, each 1 should be stacked to the top, relatively to itself only." Thanks!

Comment: @YellowShark Thanks buddy. i added sketch of how my final outcome should look alike.

Comment: Thanks, that's great - makes sense. Hope my answer gets you closer, let me know if you need any more help dialing it in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to alter the layout a little bit - those `Row` objects act as clearing elements, so that's why your `label_2` field is showing up *below* the baseline of the `label_3` textarea - because it's been cleared.

So the solution is to create 2 columns, using the `Div` class, and then drop the `wrapper_class` attribute on your fields. You can also drop the `Field` objects, and just use the field names (since you don't need to specify any attributes):

```
## forms.py
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Row, Div, Layout

class BasicForm(forms.Form):
   label_1 = forms.CharField(label='label1')
   # label_2 uses a widget with custom attribute(s)
   label_2 = forms.CharField(label='label2', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
   label_3 = forms.CharField(label='label3',help_text='This is help text', widget=forms.Textarea)
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Div('label_1', 'label_2',
                    css_class='col-md-6'
                ),
                Div(
                    'label_3',
                    css_class='col-md-6'
                ),
            ),
        )
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks! I got some other problem now. how can i set `label2` (for example) to be a`readonly` field while other fields aren't?